# How are functions scoped/namespaced within a <script> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm working with a new application at work that we're building out using Knockout.js and jQuery.  I prefer to `"use strict"` in my scripts, but since some of the libraries we're using don't work with `"use strict"` then I have to use the functional form.

I don't like placing javascript inside `<script>` tags inline, so I generally place everything in a separate file so it can be minified and gzipped by a pre-processor.

Given these criteria, I'm wondering how functions are scoped by default when you create them within a script tag.  Right now I'm just doing something like this:

```
$((function(win) {
    "use strict";

    win.myFunction = function () {
        // do stuff
    };
}(window)));
```

As you can see I'm placing functions on my `window` object so I can call them in my view.  I've noticed that I can call them in my jQuery templates without qualifying them (i.e.:  I can just call `myFunction` instead if `window.myFunction`), but I'm concerned that this will not work across browsers.  Do all browsers allow you to call functions placed in the window object without the fully-qualified name?  How could I place a function in the global scope from within my anonymous method as I've defined above?

Thanks for the insight!

Comment: You have an extra closing parenthesis, and the function you're invoking doesn't return anything, so you're passing `undefined` to the `jQuery()` function.

Comment: I do have an extra set of parenthesis (not an extra closing one), but this is shorthand for the `$(document).ready(function() { });` syntax.  See http://api.jquery.com/ready/ to see this syntax in use.

Comment: You're right, it is a full set that you don't need, and I'm very familiar with the shortcut. But you're passing `undefined` to that shortcut because you're invoking the function without a return value. As such, the shortcut for `.ready()` isn't doing anything but returning an empty jQuery object.

Comment: This is just a short example.  I've got a lot more code inside that anonymous function.  I'm using this method so I can use the function form of `"use strict"`, and also to ensure that the DOM is loaded.

Comment: Oh and the extra set of parenthesis is there to keep JSLint happy.  I know it's silly, but I do value JSLint's input :)

Comment: @Scott: Makes sense about jsLint. So you must have a return statement that's returning a function then. That too would make sense. :o)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The window object essentially *is* the global scope.  Any variable that isn't scoped to a function is a property of the window object.

You can set a global variable by setting it as a property of the window object, as you just about do:

```
window.myFunction = function() {
    // do stuff
}
```

However, it's probably not a good idea to litter your global namespace with names.  That way chaos, unmaintainable code and bizarre bugs come in.  All jQuery functions, for example, are properties or sub-properties of the `jQuery` (or `$`) object.  This means that they can define `jQuery.each` and not have to worry about collisions with a global `each` method.  You should consider doing the same with your own code: create a single global namespacing object to house all your "global" methods.

Comment: so if I create my own "global" namespace, can I just place it on the window object and access it from my view by calling `myNameSpace.whatever` instead of `window.myNameSpace.whatever` ?

Comment: @Scott I'm not entirely with you, but I expect so, yes.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  This is a much better way.  I've created my own global namespace and placed it in the `window` object.  It's working just fine.  Cheers!

Comment: But it's a good idea to use the `window.MyNamespace`, suppose that you create a MyNamespace inside a function context. If you just call MyNaespace than you are not getting the one defined in window.